# Having trouble working with a class with an array

Tags: java, oop, class, object

When i call my TruthTable class & populate it w/inputs, I can't access individual slots in the array when I'm trying to set the inputs of the AND gates?

**threeAndGates.java** -the class where the error happens

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class threeAndGates {

   public static void main(String[] args){
      LogicGate and1 = new LogicGate(LogicGate.AND);
      LogicGate and2 = new LogicGate(LogicGate.AND);
      LogicGate and3 = new LogicGate(LogicGate.AND);

      System.out.print("What is the number of Inputs? ");
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      int numOfInputs = scan.nextInt();

      System.out.print("What is the number of Outputs? ");
      int numOfOutputs = scan.nextInt();

      TruthTable Table1 = new TruthTable(numOfInputs,numOfOutputs);
      Table1.PopulateTruthTable();

      //below is where it is giving me "the type of the expression must be an array type but it resolves to TruthTable"
      for(int r = 0; r<(Math.pow(2, numOfInputs)) ; r++ ){
         and1.setInput1(Table1[r][0]);
         and1.setInput2(Table1[r][1]);
         and2.setInput1(Truth1[r][2]);
         and2.setInput2(Truth1[r][3]);
         and3.setInput1(and1.getOutput());
         and3.setInput2(and2.getOutput());

         Table1[r][numOfInputs + numOfOutputs] = and3.getOutput();
      }

      Table1.printTruthTable();
   }
}
```

**TruthTable.java**

```
public class TruthTable {
   private int numOfInputs;
   private boolean[][] table;

   public TruthTable(int inputs, int outputs){
      this.numOfInputs = inputs;
      int rows = (int) Math.pow(2,inputs);
      int columns =  inputs + outputs;
      table = new boolean[rows][columns];
   }

   public void printTruthTable(){
      for(int r = 0 ; r < table.length ; r++){
         for(int c = 0; c < table[r].length; c++)
            System.out.printf("%-5b ", table[r][c]);
         System.out.println();
      }
   }

   public String toString(){
      String outStr = new String();
      for(int r = 0; r < table.length; r++){
         for(int c = 0; c < table[r].length; c++)
            outStr += String.format("%-5b ", table[r][c]);
         outStr += '\n';
      }

      return outStr;
   }

   public boolean[][] PopulateTruthTable(){
      String s; 
      String r ="";
      int[] Line = new int[numOfInputs];
      boolean bit;

      for ( int i= 0; i < Math.pow(2,numOfInputs) ; i++){
         int x = numOfInputs - Integer.toBinaryString(i).length();
         for(int j = 0; j<x ; j++)
            r += "0"; 
         s = r + Integer.toBinaryString(i);
         for(int k=0; k<s.length() ;k++){
           Line[k] = s.charAt(k)-48;
         }  

         for(int m=0 ; m<numOfInputs ; m++){    
           if(Line[m]==1) bit = true;
           else bit = false; 
           table[i][m] = bit;
         }
         r="";
      } 
      return table;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your TruthTable class is not an Array. It contains an Array. You could add a get and set method to your TruthTable class:

```
public boolean getValueAt(int x, int y) {
   return this.table[x][y];
}

public void setValueAt(int x, int y, boolean value) {
   this.table[x][y] = value;
}
```

and use that to work with the TruthTable values.

---

This is unrelated to your problem, but when naming variables in your classes, the general practice is to use lower case. For example you have:

```
TruthTable Table1 = new TruthTable(numOfInputs,numOfOutputs);
```

would be better

```
TruthTable table1 = new TruthTable(numOfInputs,numOfOutputs);
```

and probably best as

```
TruthTable truthTable = new TruthTable(numOfInputs,numOfOutputs);
```

The better and more consistent you name things the easier it will be to read down the road.

Comment: +! - Good tip with the naming conventions! Not only will it help you read your own code in the future, but it helps us SO users help you solve your porblems faster because we can understand your code faster too!

Comment: Just the code highlighting be correct makes it so much easier for me to process, I probably should have noted also that the Class names should start uppercase also, but I thought my post was already to long.

Comment: I know what you mean. Even the method names were uppercase: `Table1.PopulateTruthTable();` :(

Answer (score 1):

Your TruthTable class isn't a mutil-dimensional array; it has a multi-dimensional array field. Therefor, you can not use the following syntax:

```
tableInstance[x][y]
```

If you TruthTable's table field was public, or better yet, it had a getter, you could do womthing like this instead...

```
tableInstance.getTable()[x][y]
```

Some languages (like C#) also support operator overloading which would allow you define the behaviour of using the `[]` index operator (or others like `+`, `/`, etc.). This would allow you to make the indexing work. Unfortunately, Java doesn't have this feature.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment than an answer but I needed more space.

If your code causes you problems later, may I make a suggestion?  Break down populateTruthTable into 2 or 3 methods, putting each loop in it's own well named method because [Each method should do exactly one thing](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/curlys-law-do-one-thing.html)

Also you probably shouldn't be accessing the array directly from the main class, instead put all the code from your main classes "for" loop into a method in the TruthTable class and call that method from main because you should [Tell an object what to do rather than asking for it's data.](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask)

I'm not trying to say you're doing it wrong or anything, you are obviously doing very well, but it's always good to pick up more coding tricks/practices as you go along and you seem like you are at the level where these would come in handy.